# C# WinForms SQL Server Express (Local Database) connectionString for unknown computer

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, connection-string

I have a WinForms application that connects to a SQL Server database. I use the following connection string

```
data source=MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB; trusted_connection=true;
```

Problem is, I need to create an installer for the application, but I do not know the name of the target computer. How can I define my connection string, so it will work on any computer the application is installed on?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which tool do you use to create the installer?

Comment: Use "data source=.; and it will pickup any default instance of SQL Server installed on target machine. If you are sure that the instance name would be 'SQLEXPRESS; then "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
Other options are embedded databseses like SQL Compact Edition.

Comment: @Kashif Yes, I'm almost certain it will be SQLEXPRESS (will ask one more, tho). Thanks, will try it on my mom's laptop, since she doesn't have anything installed on it yet :D

Comment: @Steve I will probably use SharpDevelop 4.4, since I think Visual Express will not allow me to create an installer

Comment: If the target machine does not have SQL Express installed then it wont work. Thats what I am telling you. If you are not sure that your users will have SQL Express or any other instance of SQL Server installed then you have to use then embedded databases (SQLite, SQL Compact Edition) and if you can ask (force) your users to install any instance of SQL Server then use this connection string to mention the instance name. BTW I am sure your moms computer wont have SQL Server until/unless she is like Julie Lerman -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't have the privilege to comment, so I'm posting as an answer.

using "Localhost" in the data source would do the trick
so your connection string will be like this:

```
connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB; trusted_connection=true;"
```